# @ExampleObject annotation not generated by openapi-generator

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

Generate server code using the OpenAPI Generator based on an OpenAPI specification:
OpenAPI Generator can generate code based on an OpenAPI yaml specification.

I am writing  OpenAPI specification version 3.0.1/3.0.3 with "Examples in Media Type ie RequestBody and Response". Using OpenAPI generator, it generates code where Annotation for Examples in media type is not generated.

I have tried the following but none has generated Annotation ie @ExampleObject for Examples in RequestBody and Response.

```
| Source                  | Server Generator        | Integrate swagger to springboot |
|-------------------------|-------------------------|---------------------------------|
| Swagger Editor          | Swagger codegen         | Springdoc-openapi               |
| New Swagger Editor      | Swagger codegen         | Springdoc-openapi               |
| Generate using Cmd      | OpenAPI generator 6.1.0 | Springdoc-openapi               |
| My Project              | OpenAPI generator 4.3.1 | Springfox                       |
| Blog-Maven project      | OpenAPI generator 5.3.0 | Springfox                       |
```

Below you can find the OpenAPI Specification I tried:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Swagger
  description: OpenAPI 3.0 specification. 
  version: 1.0.11

paths:
  /test:
    put:
      summary: Test Examples
      description: Test Examples
      requestBody:
        description: Test Examples
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: string
            examples:
              example1:
                description: Example 1
                value: Test string 1
                summary: Example-1
              example2:
                description: Example 2
                value: Test string 2
                summary: Example-2
              example3:
                description: Example 3
                value: Test string 3
                summary: Example-3
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
              examples:
                example1:
                  description: Example 1
                  value: Test response 1
                  summary: Example-1
                example2:
                  description: Example 2
                  value: Test response 2
                  summary: Example-2
                example3:
                  description: Example 3
                  value: Test response 3
                  summary: Example-3
        '400':
          description: Invalid 
        '404':
          description: Not found
        '405':
          description: Validation exception
```

Though Examples are displayed in Swagger Editor but I need to generate Annotation for Examples using OpenAPI generator. I don't have an option to manually add @ExampleObject annotation.

Is there any way to generate annotation for Examples using openapi-generator?
Please correct me if I misunderstood anything.